# Tensorflow parameter rework to tuple

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have code in several places that takes a tuple, but can take a list, or single number. Usage is where I want an image size like (h,w), for example (256,128), but it also can take [256,128] or just 128 to be (128,128) or even a single float that gets repeated and cast to int.

Here's my code:

```
    if isinstance(mp_reduction_shape, int) or isinstance(mp_reduction_shape, float):
        self.mp_reduction_h = int(mp_reduction_shape)
        self.mp_reduction_w = int(mp_reduction_shape)
    elif isinstance(mp_reduction_shape, tuple) or isinstance(mp_reduction_shape, list):
        self.mp_reduction_h = int(mp_reduction_shape[0])
        if len(mp_reduction_shape) == 1:
            self.mp_reduction_w = int(mp_reduction_shape[0])
        else:
            self.mp_reduction_w = int(mp_reduction_shape[1])
    else:
        self.mp_reduction_h = int(mp_reduction_shape[0])
        self.mp_reduction_w = int(mp_reduction_shape[1])
```

Is there a builtin function to do this in tensorflow or python?
Is this even the right approach for this type of parameter passing?

Comment: Making sure tensor shapes match up is very helpful in finding and preventing problems in your model. I would be very explicit with them. I don't think TF will complain if you pass a list instead of a tuple, but a tuple is the most appropriate data type so you might as well.

Comment: If I get what @warpri81 is trying to say `if isinstance(obj, tuple)` would be more appropriate test?  The function iter() may be useful for you in your code @Richard Keene.